# Java compilation failure when using generics parameter in inner class

Tags: java, generics, inner-classes

Please take a look at the code snippet below:

```
interface IFoo<E>{
    void doFoo(E env);
}

class A<E>{
    public void doA(E env){}
}

public class Foo<E> implements IFoo<E>{
    public A<E> a;

    @Override
    public void doFoo(E env) {
        a.doA(env);
    }

    private class FooInner<E> implements IFoo<E>{

        @Override
        public void doFoo(E env) {
            a.doA(env);
        }
    }
}
```

Eclipse complains inside of private inner class `a.doA(env)` with the following message.

```
The method doA(E) in the type A<E> is not applicable for the arguments (E)
```

It doesn't seem like accessibility issue because non-static inner class have an access to all instance variables of the outter class. It looks like I defined my generics wrong somewhere. Can anyone explain me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of the enclosing class is part of the type of the inner class. `FooInner` is *already* parameterized by `E`, because it's part of the outer class; the explicit parameterization is redundant and incorrect, because it's actually trying to introduce a new type parameter using the same name as the existing one. Just remove the `<E>` in `private class FooInner<E>`, and you're golden.

Answer (score 6):

You've used the same generic parameter name for the inner class, so the type `E` of the inner class is *shadowing* the `E` of the outer class.

Remove generic parameter from the inner class, like this:

```
public class Foo<E> implements IFoo<E>{

    ...

    private class FooInner implements IFoo<E>{ // "E" here is the same "E" from Foo

        @Override
        public void doFoo(E env) {
            a.doA(env);
        }
    }
}
```